# split string by any amount of whitespace in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

I know how to split a string so the words between the delimitor into elements in an array using .explode() by " ".

But that only splits the string by a single whitespace character. How can I split by any amount of whitespace?

So an element in the array end when whitespace is found and the next element in the array starts when the first next non-whitespace character is found.

So something like `"The quick   brown        fox"` turns into an array with The, quick, brown, and fox are elements in the returned array.

And `"jumped over the lazy dog"` also splits so each word is an individual element in the returned array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split string by white-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206953/split-string-by-white-space)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like this:

```
preg_split('#\s+#', $string, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourSplitArray=preg_split('/[\ \n\,]+/', $your_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 preg_split(" +", "hypertext language    programming"); //for one or more whitespaces
```

Answer (score -1):

you can see here: [PHP explode() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp)

```
<?php
    $str = "Hello world. It's a beautiful day.";
    print_r (explode(" ",$str));
?>
```

will return:

```
Array ( [0] => Hello [1] => world. [2] => It's [3] => a [4] => beautiful [5] => day. )
```